# How did the conjugate were able to get inside the inverse?

Tags: matrices

Show that $$U := (A-iI)(A+iI)^{-1} $$ is a unitary matrix, where A is a hermitian matrix.

The first part of the answer says: $$ U^{*} =[(A+iI)^{-1}]^{*}(A-iI)^{*} = [(A+iI)^{-1}]^{*}(A+iI)= [(A+iI)^{*}]^{-1}(A+iI)=[(A-iI)]^{-1}(A+iI) $$

I can't understand how did the conjugate were able to get inside the inverse?

Comment: Conjugation commutes with inverse. By the properties of conjugation $A^*(A^{-1})^*=(A^{-1}A)^*=I^*=I$, and so $(A^{-1})^*$ is the inverse of $A^*$, i.e $(A^{-1})^*=(A^*)^{-1}$.

Comment: A point of vacabulary : transformation $A \to U$ is a version of **Cayley's transform**. This may help you to find further references.